# listening for multicast traffic on mutiple networks

Tags: python, sockets, networking, multicast

I currently have the following code that receive multicast data.

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sock.bind(('', 24003))
mreq = struct.pack("=4sl", socket.inet_aton("238.210.10.1"), socket.INADDR_ANY)
sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, mreq)
```

I have two network cards but the code only listens to messages sent to 127.0.0.1. How do I listen to all multicast message on any network card? without hard-coding them.

Comment: Tried to use threads or the Twisted framework?

Comment: The [Python `select` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html) allows you to wait for input on multiple sockets.  I agree that Twisted would be good, but I recommend `select` over threads.

Comment: @RandomDownvoter care to explain the down vote? so I can try to improve the question.

Comment: @ahenderson It must have been the properly worded title, accurate tagging, or unbroken english in the question body

Comment: @japreiss: Threads are a whole lot simpler when you don't need to share any data between connections, but a whole lot less simpler when you do. So, unless you need to handle thousands of connections, that's the best deciding factor. (If you _do_ need to handle thousands of connections, you can't use threads… but at that point, you can consider `gevent`, which has effectively the same simplicity tradeoffs.)

Comment: Thanks everyone who has given a constructive comment. As it stands, I've required the user to pass parameter for the interface address of the network card the application should listen and broadcast on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`struct ip_mreq`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/ip.7.html) allows you to select *one* interface to join your desired multicast group on. Specifying `INADDR_ANY` lets the system do that for you by looking up interface on the matching route in the routing table (it means *any* interface, not *all* interfaces). If you are on Unix you can see which interface is selected for group membership with [`netstat -ng`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/netstat/).

If you want to join the same group on *all* interfaces, then enumerate them with [`if_nameindex(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/if_nameindex.3.html) (you'll have to figure out how to do this in Python), create a socket per interface, `bind(2)` and join (`setsockopt(2)`) the group using the interface index or address, then poll the sockets with `select`.

Comment: The only tricky bit when accessing the `if_nameindex` API via `ctypes` is that there's a type `struct if_nameindex` and a function `if_nameindex` which you have to keep straight (just like with `stat`). Otherwise, it's pretty much trivial if you've ever used `ctypes` and know how to `LoadLibrary('libc.so')` (or `libc.dylib`).

Comment: Joining a multicast group isn't 'listening'. It's a much misused term in UDP, where it really has no meaning at all. Best to avoid it really.

Comment: Yeah, I agree, "listening" is not the right term here (I knew I could count on you to find flaws in my answers :), will try to re-phrase.

Answer (score 2):

1. There is no 'listening' on a UDP socket. It's a TCP term. You need to *join* the multicast group *via all applicable interfaces,* by looping over them. That ensures that the IGMP JOIN message is sent to all the required networks, so they will know to send multicasts to you.
2. Depending in your platform you need to either bind to the multicast address itself (Linux) or INADDR_ANY = 0.0.0.0 (Windows). I'm not sure which camp Unix falls into but I suspect in this case it's the Windows camp. That ensures that you can receive datagrams via any interface.